# Return value from set function

Tags: matlab, oop

So given a class I would like to have a property who set function returns some value to indicate if it succeeded in setting the value.

```
classdef Foo
  properties
    bar;
  end
  methods
    function this = set.bar(this, instanceOfBar)
      if instanceOfBar.x < 5 & instanceOfBar < 10
        this.bar = instanceOfBar;
        return something to tell me that this instance of bar matched my criteria
      else
        return some value to tell me that it did not match
      end
    end
  end
end

classdef bar
  properties
    x;
    y;
  end
end
```

So I would have a bunch of bar objects and I would like to pass them to foo until it accepts one of them. I know I could do this outside class but I would like to have all data validation happening inside the class.

I've messed around with trying to get the set function to return another value but nothing has worked. Is this possible?

If not my workaround would be to add a property who's sole purpose is to report if the last set was successful or not and check that after each call. So if its not possible does anyone else have a good workaround for this missing feature?

Edit: In response to first answer

```
if set(myobject, 'A', 1) == 'Good'
  execute code
else
  do something else
```

In testing this does not work. Did I misunderstand your answer?

Comment: have you tired setting `Foo` as a handle class `classdef Foo < handle`?

Comment: Yes, no effect on the setter functions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to subclass [`hgsetget`](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/matlab/ref/hgsetget.html) in order to be able to [use the get/set interface](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/matlab/matlab_oop/implementing-a-set-get-interface-for-properties.html):

```
classdef foo < hgsetget
    properties
        A
    end
    methods 
        function obj = set.A(obj,val)
        if val == 1
            obj.A = val;
            disp('Good')
        else
            disp('Bad')
        end
        end
    end
end
```

In action:

```
myobj = foo
myobj = 
  foo with properties:
    A: []

set(myobj,'A',1)
Good

get(myobj)
A: 1
```

Comment: I need to be able to test programmatically if it succeeds. See question edit.

Comment: @csleys After you set the property, query it and compare `get(myobj,'A') == 1`. Or do you want to notify events to listeners?

Comment: I've expanded my example. What I want is to pass a object to another object and have it perform data validation and tell me if the passed object is acceptable via a boolean return or something else.

Comment: @csleys Have you tried to `get(myobj,'A')`? The `set()` does NOT return a value, it sets it, then you can `get()` it!

Comment: I understand that. This is obviously a failure on my part to explain my question. Is it _possible_ to return a value from the set function? Your answer does provide an alternative that I may use but I'd like to pin down the return question as well. If possible I would like to use the "obj.bar = x" notation rather then the function notation of "set(obj, 'bar', x)", "get(obj, 'bar')" because the people I'm developing this application for prefer the previous notation. Thank you for your help. Does this make sense?

Comment: The set/get interface ALREADY supports dot notation. As I said before, set, give a value to a property, THEN you can check for that value. Whatever you are trying to accomplish, you're making a conceptual mistake. Once the object has been assigned a value, you can check if that value correpsonds to what you want, programmatically. The information in your example is simply not sufficient to understand what you're trying to do.

Comment: Indirectly you've answered my question and provided alternatives. I'll take some time to consider my goals since you clearly understand Matlab better then most. And it would not be the first time I've over complicated something. :)